# AmazonS3 Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the credentials of amazon to make uploaded image. Net, but when I updated to 2.0 sdk and code it returns the error Access Denied.

Below is the code:

```
            PutObjectResponse response;

                // objeto que requisitará todos os componentes necessários para enviar os arquivos ao servidor
                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[nomeBalde],
                    Key = keyname,
                    InputStream = pObject
                };

                //configura a permissão do arquivo no servidor
                request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;

                //salvo o arquivo no servidor abrindo uma conexão                
                 response = client.PutObject(request);


            return "Objeto salvo com sucesso.";
```

Comment: Where are you specifying your credentials? I don't see it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

before uploading you have to set permission to that file as public.

```
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(....);

client.setObjectAcl(bucketName.getName(), fileName, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
```